Next.js installation
i have node installed on my windows pc. I wanted to install nextjs
i am getting a bunch of errors.
Can someone help.
C:\Users\MD AREEB  AKHTAR>npx create-next-app@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\MD AREEB  AKHTAR\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\MD AREEB  AKHTAR\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
